# How to make portable CCleaner detect portable web browsers?

Tags: portable, ccleaner

Is it possible? Because I tried it and it seems that it doesn't detect the portable apps the browsers. I'm currently using Google Chrome for browsing and Firefox for downloading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to edit [portable CCleaner's i](http://forum.piriform.com/lofiversion/index.php/t23128.html)ni file with something like:

```
Include29=PATH|C:\Program Files\Windows NT\PORTABLES\PortGoogleCHROME\Profil\Default\|*.*
```

Where the path off course should lead to your portable browsers

Comment: yeah, that was just the answer that I was looking for, thanks man!

Comment: You know, I learn from searching myself as well! Great to hear it worked

Comment: Link's dead. Do you still have a pointer to a similar source? I cannot find the original page in the [Web Archive](http://wayback.archive.org/web/*/http://forum.piriform.com/lofiversion/index.php/t23128.html).

Comment: [I think this link will be of help](http://www.piriform.com/docs/ccleaner/advanced-usage/ccleaner-ini-files/how-to-clean-user-data-from-non-standard-mozilla-browsers) @RobW

Comment: @IvoFlipse Yep, nice one.