# how to add other browsers for cleaning in ccleaner?

Tags: windows-10, windows-8, browser, ccleaner

on w8.1 and w10 both 64 bit, apart from firefox, ie11(8.1) edge(10), chrome, I also have Palemoon, Light and Basilisk installed.

ccleaner 5.47 cleans other browsers, including firefox and palemoon, but it doesn't clean Light and Basilisk.

what is to be added in ccleaner.ini or in winapp2.ini (i guess these are the names) so that ccleaner will find profiles of these browsers also and clean these.

I had asked on ccleaner forum about palemoon some 2 years ago and got no working reply.

this link suggests a method for portable web browsers, that the members here said is working method.

> [How to make portable CCleaner detect portable web browsers?](https://superuser.com/questions/107040/how-to-make-portable-ccleaner-detect-portable-web-browsers)
>
> You have to edit portable CCleaner's ini file with something like:
>
> Include29=PATH|C:\Program Files\Windows
>   NT\PORTABLES\PortGoogleCHROME\Profil\Default\|*.*
>
> Where the path off course should lead to your portable browsers

Is there any similar method to add Light and Basilisk also?

Thanks.